# SFML: Object's shape not rendered on the window

Tags: c++, rendering, game-loop, sfml, oop

I want to be able to render `sf::CircleShape` (representing pointwise charges) when pressing mouse buttons on the window. The problem is easy enough, however the shapes that I want to draw are attributes of a class `Charge`. The `Scene` class implements window management and event polling/ rendering methods and it has an attribute `std::vector<Charge> distribution`.

The idea is to update the `distribution` variable everytime the event `sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed` is recorded and then draw the charges' shapes within such vector. For some reason I cannot make it work and I think it's due to the object being created and destroyed within the event loop.

I have a main that looks like this

```
#include "Scene.h"

int main(){

  Scene scene;

  while(scene.running())
  {
    scene.update();
    scene.render();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

with the header `Scene.h` declaring the class methods for window management and event polling

```
#include "Charge.h"

class Scene
{
    private:
        sf::RenderWindow* window;
        sf::Event event;
        std::vector<Charge> distribution;
    
public:
        Scene();
        virtual ~Scene();

        bool running();
        void polling();
        void render();
        void update();
};
```

The definitions of the methods instantiated in the game loop are

```
void Scene::update(){this -> polling();}

void Scene::polling()
{
    while(this -> window -> pollEvent(this -> event))
    {
        switch(this -> event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed: this -> window -> close();
                break;

            case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                this -> distribution.push_back(Charge(*this -> window, sf::Mouse::getPosition(*this -> window));
                std::cout << "Distribution size = " << distribution.size() << "\n";
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Scene::render()
{
    this -> window -> clear(sf::Color::Black);

    for(auto charge: this -> distribution)
    {
        charge.render(*this -> window);
    }

    this -> window -> display();
}
```

The `window` object is instatiated in the cosntrutor of `Scene`. Now `Charge.h` declares the class

```
class Charge
{
    private:
        sf::CircleShape shape;

    public:
        Charge(const sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Vector2i position);
        virtual ~Charge();

        void render(sf::RenderTarget& target);
};
```

and the definition of its methods is the following

```
Charge::Charge(const sf::RenderWindow& window, sf::Vector2i position)
{
    std::cout << "Charge's object created!" << std::endl;
    this -> shape.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(static_cast<float>(position.x), static_cast<float>(position.y)));
    this -> shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(255,50,50));
    this -> shape.setRadius(25.f);
}

Charge::~Charge(){std::cout << "Charge's object destroyed!" << std::endl;}

void Charge::render(sf::RenderTarget& target)
{
    target.draw(this -> shape);
}
```

I added printing on terminal in the constructor and destructor. The execution of the program does not render any of the objects' shapes when mouse buttons are pressed. The terminal however reports

```
Charge's object created! # <-- Here I pressed the mouse's button
Charge's object destroyed!
Distribution size = 1
Charge's object destroyed!
Charge's object destroyed!
Charge's object destroyed!
Charge's object destroyed!
Charge's object destroyed!
Charge's object destroyed!
Charge's object destroyed! # <-- And it goes on and on as long as the window is not closed.
```

I tried to approach the problem in various ways but none have worked so far. Any idea?

Comment: You might want to make your Charge noncopyable (check boost's implementation), and add the default move ctor/move copy function...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578331/sfml-objects-shape-not-rendered-in-window).

Answer (score 1):

This block of code will be copying each object of type `Charge` for every iteration and assigning to the variable called `charge`.

```cpp
  for(auto charge: this -> distribution)
  {
      charge.render(*this -> window);
  }
```

You need to change `auto` to `auto&` because you want to use a reference to the object itself not a copy of it. In most cases, this is the right approach in range-based for loops.

```cpp
  for(auto& charge: this -> distribution)
  {
      charge.render(*this -> window);
  }
```

The first "Charge's object destroyed!" message is coming from the `push_back` method from the vector. Use `emplace_back` instead. It constructs the object inside the vector without doing any copying. It 'moves' the data to be exact.

```cpp
this->distribution.emplace_back(*this -> window, sf::Mouse::getPosition(*this -> window));
```

There should not be any problems with the rendering in general. I don't see any issues with that. If you can show the problem in a gif, that would be better.

Comment: This solves the issue they report about having the object destroyed every frame, but does it solve the issue about the object not being rendered?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I am not sure if there is a problem with the rendering in general. I use this technique in rendering big chunks of primitives, and it works well enough. Not sure how this causes a problem though.